# I can't insert data into my database but I don't have any errors

Tags: php

This is my php code. Can you please help me. There's no data in my database.

```
    <?php

    require_once("dbconnect.php");

    session_start();


    for ($x = 0; x < $_POST['reimcounter']; $x++) {

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $tin = $_POST['tin'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $particulars = $_POST['particulars'];
    $referencenumber = $_POST['refno'];
    $total = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $_POST['total' . $x]));
    $nonvat = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $_POST['nonvat' . 
    $x]));
```

Is there anything wrong with my insert code?

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rtco_cms.dbo.Reimbursement VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
    ?, ?, ?)";

    $params = array($date, $tin, $SESSION['empid'], $address, 
    $SESSION['clientid'], $particulars, $referencenumber, $nonvat, $total);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    }

    header("location: ../reimbursement.php");


    ?>
```

Comment: You probably **are** getting an error, you're just not checking for it. If the query fails, `sqlserv_query()` will return `false`. Check for that like they do in Example #1 of [the documentation](http://php.net/sqlsrv_query).

Comment: Insert statement is wrong !!

Comment: There's no error showing. The problem is it is not inserting into my database. Is my code wrong?

Comment: Use Error log first.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$params = array($date, $tin, $SESSION['empid'], $address, 
$SESSION['clientid'], $particulars, $referencenumber, $nonvat, $total);
```

to

```
$params = array($date, $tin, $_SESSION['empid'], $address, 
$_SESSION['clientid'], $particulars, $referencenumber, $nonvat, $total);
```

Session variable calling is wrong. Hope it helps

Update your insert query for example see this query:

```
tsql= "INSERT INTO dbo.vF_events (
        username,
        Rft,
        Ging,
        description,
        date,
        trdate) 
        VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $var = array($username, $sort, $ag,     $description, $date, $trdate);
        if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var))
             {
        die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
             }
        echo "record added";
```

Comment: $params = array($date, $tin, $_POST['name-' . $x], $address, $_POST['client-' . $x], $particulars, $referencenumber, $nonvat, $total);

Comment: <td><input type="hidden" name="name-0" id="employeeid-0" class="form-control"><input id="employee-0" type="text" class="form-control employee"></td>                                                                <td><input type="hidden" name="client-0" id="clientid-0" class="form-control"><input id="client-0" type="text" class="form-control client"></td></td>

Comment: Update your insert query as I have shown in example.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO rtco_cms.dbo.Reimbursement VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

 $params = array($date, $tin, $_POST['name-' . $x], $address, $_POST['client-' . $x], $particulars, $referencenumber, $nonvat, $total);
 
 if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params))
 {
  die('Error: ' . sqlsrv_errors());
 }
 echo "record added";

Comment: Where are the table field names

Comment: $date = $_POST['date'];
 $tin = $_POST['tin'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $particulars = $_POST['particulars'];
 $referencenumber = $_POST['refno'];
 $total = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $_POST['total-' . $x]));
 $nonvat = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $_POST['nonvat-' . $x]));

Comment: this is the table field names

Comment: Please see how I had written the insert query. field names and values are separated.